# Issue with concurrent POST requests with Jersey REST and Neo4j environment

Tags: java, rest, jersey, neo4j

I have **Jersery Rest service** and i am using **Neo4j Embedded Database** to serve requests with data.

Now when i make concurrent **GET** requests it works fine.

But when i make concurrent **POST** requests It gives Following Exception :

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@62f1ca5e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:296)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:85)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
```

I know the problem is if there is already instance of neo4j running we can't access the same with another thread.

**Solution** would be [Neo4j HA](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-how.html)

But as i dont have enough time to configure Neo4j HA cluster, can anyone please suggest me on How can i make **POST** request to be single threaded (means no concurrent threads accessing Neo4j at the same time).

Any link or tutorial.

**Edit**

I am starting neo4j like this:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/GraphDB");'
```

and in `finally` block i am doing

```
graphdb.shutdown();
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to start the embedded Neo4j instance per each POST request. Post the code on how you are starting/stopping the embedded neo4j

Comment: @Pangea I am starting neo4j 'GraphDatabaseService graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/GraphDB");' and in finally block i am doin 'graphdb.shutdown();'

Comment: What `finally` block?

Comment: @Tichodroma leave it bro Help Yourself first :P

Comment: If you want help, provide context. I will not guess what you are doing.

Comment: @Tichodroma- 'Finally' r u asking me finally. Its the basic idiom you learn in programming. BTW, don't abuse your power, down voting something which you don't understand won't help.

Comment: @Shiv GraphDatabaseService is thread-safe. Initialize it once in ServletContextListener and shut it down in the same listener. With the code you have provided I believe you are doing it per request. If not little bit more context (like Tichodroma was requestig) would help

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how `GET` requests are working in this case, perhaps someone from Neo4j team could best provide for an explanation. I'm assuming that you are initializing and shutting `graphdb` with each request. Also, I haven't been in touch with Java lately, my suggestion may not be accurate.

The way I think I would deal with this is by *not* initializing and shutting `graphdb` with each request. The reason being that Neo4j locks on a graph database directory and won't allow a new thread to re-initialize an embedded instance on the same directory (read thread-safe). Instead, I'd rather use a singleton class which exposed `graphdb` and re-use it as a shared object in the JVM. `graphdb.shutdown()` could occur in a shutdown hook for your Jersey service (`graphdb` shuts down only when the service goes down). This aligns with what Pangea suggested, `ServletContextListener` is a good place to do this. However, implementation may vary with Jersey.

Finally, I'd be polite with people who are trying to help out by editing your question, commenting and asking for context around your problem. :)

Comment: Great Solution, It was rather a design problem rather than something very neo4j specific. So We would keep it that way -> Initializing the graphdb with service startup and it shuts down as service goes down. Thanks again!(Also writing this on behalf of my team-mate who originally asked the question).

Answer (score 1):

too late to answer this but again if anyone is facing the same issue ,this is how i fixed it.
Maintain a singleton class. i.e,

```
      GraphDatabaseService graphdb=null;
      if(graphdb.isAvailable()&& graphdb!=null)
       {
            return graphdb;
       }
       else
        {
           graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/GraphDB");
         return graphdb;
        }
```