# How to make Jersey Rest POST request to be synchronized

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How can i make Jersey REST POST request Synchronized so that if one request is in process no other request can be made.

i tried making method `synchronized` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What use case do you have?

Comment: @Tichodroma how does it matters??

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, please provide context. I doubt that you are trying to solve your real problem at the correct location of your code stack. That's how.

Comment: i am accessing neo4j database through this post request and in neo4j embedded multiple instances for same database dont work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916676/issue-with-concurrent-post-requests-with-jersey-rest-and-neo4j-environment

Comment: Are you sure all request threads are accessing the same instance of the class?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to `synchronize` your service methods and start / stop your `GraphDatabaseService` per request it might be interesting to start your `GraphDatabaseService` in a `ServletContextListener` and then access it through the web application's context. This takes advantage of the fact that `GraphDatabaseService` is thread safe.

Perhaps a listener like this:

```
public class ExampleListener implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("graphDb", new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("/tmp/GraphDB"));
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ((GraphDatabaseService)sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("graphDb")).shutdown();
  }

}
```

which you can initialize in your web.xml like this:

```xml
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.example.ExampleListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and then utilize in a REST method like this:

```
@POST
public void graphOperation(@Context ServletContext context) {
  GraphDatabaseService graphDb = (GraphDatabaseService)context.getAttribute("graphDb");
  // Graph operations here...
}
```

You could even add your `ServletContext` to your service class constructor and get the attributes you need as member fields of your service class to make it more convenient.